# Go Back to Default 2D Animation Window

Tags: animation, 2d, workspaces

When I start Blender and select 2D animation, I get the window of the white canvas against a dark grey background.  When I accidentally scroll, the whole thing shifts and I go into 3D mode and I seem unable to get that canvas back with the white against the dark grey.

The only solution I currently am able to do is close the window and reopen a new default 2d animation work space, but I think there must be a better way than that.

Thanks.[image: bl[![][1][1]]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an easy way.

The view you get initially is through the camera in a white background. The dark grey is the passepartout of the camera.

One way it to click the camera icon:

[image: Camera icon]

or the shortcut <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to enter the camera view.